# No cv2.pyd file after cmake build

Tags: python, opencv, opencv-contrib

I am hoping to use additonal algorithms in opencv-contrib in opencv. I am trying to build opencv with the Non Free Algorithms in contrib.

I am new to using cmake.

I was able to complete the configure/generate phases in cmake build, to build opencv (Attaching the configuration). When I build using Visual Studio, there is no cv2.pyd generated.

I do see a cv2.cp37-win_amd64.pyd file though. It is already available in the site-packages folder, when I pip install the .ee file generated from the camke build.

Following was the output of the Generate Step:

---

```
Selecting Windows SDK version to target Windows 10.0.16299.
libjpeg-turbo: VERSION = 2.0.2, BUILD = opencv-4.1.0-dev-libjpeg-turbo
found Intel IPP (ICV version): 2019.0.0 [2019.0.0 Gold]
at: /openCV/opencv-master/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
found Intel IPP Integration Wrappers sources: 2019.0.0
at: /openCV/opencv-master/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
Could not find OpenBLAS include. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
Could not find OpenBLAS lib. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
Could NOT find BLAS (missing: BLAS_LIBRARIES) 
LAPACK requires BLAS
A library with LAPACK API not found. Please specify library location.
Could NOT find JNI (missing: JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH) 
VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
OpenCV Python: during development append to PYTHONPATH: /openCV/opencv-master/build/python_loader
Excluding from source files list: modules/imgproc/src/corner.avx.cpp
Excluding from source files list: modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.avx2.cpp
Excluding from source files list: modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.sse4_1.cpp
Excluding from source files list: modules/imgproc/src/resize.avx2.cpp
Excluding from source files list: modules/imgproc/src/resize.sse4_1.cpp
Excluding from source files list: modules/imgproc/src/sumpixels.avx512_skx.cpp
Registering hook 'INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn': /openCV/opencv-master/modules/dnn/cmake/hooks/INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn.cmake
opencv_dnn: filter out cuda4dnn source code
Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/dnn/layers/layers_common.avx.cpp
Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/dnn/layers/layers_common.avx2.cpp
Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/dnn/layers/layers_common.avx512_skx.cpp
Excluding from source files list: modules/features2d/src/fast.avx2.cpp
Excluding from source files list: modules/calib3d/src/undistort.avx2.cpp
Could NOT find Doxygen (missing: DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
OpenCL samples are skipped: OpenCL SDK is required

General configuration for OpenCV 4.1.0-dev =====================================
Version control: unknown

Platform:
Timestamp: 2019-06-17T02:43:38Z
Host: Windows 10.0.16299 AMD64
CMake: 3.15.0-rc1
CMake generator: Visual Studio 14 2015
CMake build tool: C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin/MSBuild.exe
MSVC: 1900

CPU/HW features:
Baseline: SSE SSE2
requested: SSE2

C/C++:
Built as dynamic libs?: YES
C++ Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe (ver 19.0.24215.1)
C++ flags (Release): /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi /fp:fast /arch:SSE /arch:SSE2 /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP8 /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG /Zi
C++ flags (Debug): /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi /fp:fast /arch:SSE /arch:SSE2 /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP8 /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
C Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
C flags (Release): /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi /fp:fast /arch:SSE /arch:SSE2 /MP8 /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG /Zi
C flags (Debug): /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi /fp:fast /arch:SSE /arch:SSE2 /MP8 /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
Linker flags (Release): /machine:X86 /INCREMENTAL:NO /debug
Linker flags (Debug): /machine:X86 /debug /INCREMENTAL 
ccache: NO
Precompiled headers: YES
Extra dependencies:
3rdparty dependencies:

OpenCV modules:
To be built: calib3d core dnn features2d flann gapi highgui imgcodecs imgproc ml objdetect photo stitching ts video videoio
Disabled: world
Disabled by dependency: -
Unavailable: java js python2 python3
Applications: examples apps
Documentation: NO
Non-free algorithms: YES

Windows RT support: NO

GUI: 
Win32 UI: YES
VTK support: NO

Media I/O: 
ZLib: build (ver 1.2.11)
JPEG: build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.0.2-62)
WEBP: build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
PNG: build (ver 1.6.37)
TIFF: build (ver 42 - 4.0.10)
JPEG 2000: build (ver 1.900.1)
OpenEXR: build (ver 2.3.0)
HDR: YES
SUNRASTER: YES
PXM: YES
PFM: YES

Video I/O:
DC1394: NO
FFMPEG: YES (prebuilt binaries)
avcodec: YES (58.35.100)
avformat: YES (58.20.100)
avutil: YES (56.22.100)
swscale: YES (5.3.100)
avresample: YES (4.0.0)
GStreamer: NO
DirectShow: YES
Media Foundation: YES
DXVA: NO

Parallel framework: Concurrency

Trace: YES (with Intel ITT)

Other third-party libraries:
Intel IPP: 2019.0.0 Gold [2019.0.0]
at: /openCV/opencv-master/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
Intel IPP IW: sources (2019.0.0)
at: /openCV/opencv-master/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
Lapack: NO
Eigen: NO
Custom HAL: NO
Protobuf: build (3.5.1)

OpenCL: YES (NVD3D11)
Include path: /openCV/opencv-master/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
Link libraries: Dynamic load

Python (for build): C:/Anaconda/python.exe

Java: 
ant: NO
JNI: NO
Java wrappers: NO
Java tests: NO

Install to: /openCV/opencv-master/build/install


Configuring done
Generating done
```

---

I do see a .egg file created. However when i install using the .egg file, the additional algorithms SIFT/SURF are not available.

I also do see python samples in the samples folder,but no cv2.pyd file.

I was wondering if someone could guide me, in terms of getting opencv to work with the additional algorithms.

Comment: The same thing happened to me. Does anybody know this problem?